# iOS - Multi-threading - Display view with Searching... and execute code simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to fetch JSON data and decode it, while simultaneously unhiding a view that shows a `UIActivityIndicator` and `UILabel` (@"searching...") so the user knows the app is searching.

Here's how it should work:

1. User hits "Search Button"
2. `IBAction` method unhides the searching view and fetches and decodes the data simultaneously (I can do these separately, not together).
3. push a new view onto the stack using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:]` after the search has completed.

I've tried using dispatch_queue but doing that wouldn't let me use the push a new view onto the stack without bypassing the other code altogether (at least the way I was doing it). I've been told to use `NSConnection`, but I've looked at the API and am clueless as to how to accomplish this using it.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);

dispatch_async(myQueue, 
^{ 
    //...URL Request, parse JSON, etc.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
    ^{
        searchingView.hidden = NO;
        [spinner startAnimating];

      });
 });

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aSegue"];
```

This way skips all the code and immediately performs the segue.
If I put it inside the dispatch_queue with the rest of the code, it executes the code, but doesn't perform the segue. Finally, using this method, it first performs the search and THEN displays the view. I need the opposite.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I've tried using dispatch_queue but doing that wouldn't let me use the push a new view onto the stack without bypassing the other code altogether (at least the way I was doing it)." Can you explain better this part? I don't see a problem but you seem to see one.

Comment: @FábioOliveira Added the code above as an example with subsequent explanation of the issue.

Comment: I think thelaws has posted a correct answer. You update the UI to notify a search is ongoing, get the JSON and process it in the background and update the UI in the main thread after it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would display the searching view before dispatching the work, and use the dispatch to the main queue to perform the segue after the JSON has be read and parsed.

```
searchingView.hidden = NO;
[spinner startAnimating];

dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{ 
    //...URL Request, parse JSON, etc.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aSegue"];
    });
});
```